# How to parse the following "N1+に必要となる＋N2"?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure whether or not I have learnt this grammar before. I am reading a book about OpenCV and found a sentence as follows.

> OpenCVを効果的に用いるのに必要となるコンピュータビジョンについての一般的な背景知識もあわせて説明します。

The confusing part is the grammar

```
N1+に必要となる+N2
```

where

```
N1=OpenCVを効果的に用いるの
```

and

```
N2=コンピュータビジョンについての一般的な背景知識
```

I know

- `N1をN2とする` that means let N1 be N2.
- `NをNa-adjにする` or `Nをi-adj-stemくする` that means making N a condition represented by the adjective.

Is it possible to say the following?

> OpenCVを効果的に用いるのに必要と**する**コンピュータビジョンについての一般的な背景知識

Comment: Does it really say 「効果に用いる」?

Comment: Would you agree that it makes more sense to parse N2 as 「コンピュータビジョンについての一般的な背景知識」 rather than 「コンピュータヴィジョン」? I'm the very opposite of tech-savvy but I'm pretty sure you don't need computer vision in any capacity to use a software library, while you probably want to have some general background knowledge about the thing the library is made for.

Comment: @goldbrick: Yes. You are correct!

Comment: Oops.「コンピュータ**ヴィ**ジョン」 is just a typo for 「コンピュータ**ビ**ジョン」.  I didn't intend anything by that change, in case it bothered you.

Comment: ＠goldbrick: I did not notice the typo. No problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「Noun 1 + に必要{ひつよう}となる + Noun 2」

can only mean:

> "Noun **2** (which is) necessary/required for Noun **1**"

because「Noun 1 + に必要となる」 functions as a relative clause modifying 「Noun 2」.  In other words, **between Noun 1 and Noun 2, the latter is the "main" noun of the whole phrase**.

Thus,

> 「OpenCVを効果的{こうかてき}に用{もち}いるの**に必要となる**コンピュータビジョン」

means:

> "the computer vision (technology) necessary/required for effectively utilizing OpenCV"

For those who are wondering, the 「の」 in 「用いるの」 is a nominalizer, making it possible to treat the phrase 「OpenCVを効果的に用いるの」 just like a noun.  That whole phrase is what the questioner is calling "N1".

Finally,

> Is it possible to say the following?
>
> OpenCVを効果的に用いるのに必要と**する**コンピュータビジョン

No, it is not possible.  「なる」 and 「する」 mean very different things; therefore, they cannot be used interchangeably.  I could not think of an exception.

Comment: XがYを必要とする。
YがXを必要となる。

Are they equal?

Comment: ^ 「XがYを必要とする」は「YがX**に**必要だ。/ 必要となる。」に近いですね。。

Comment: @Chocolate: I don't understand how to read `「YがXに必要だ。/ 必要となる。」`.

Comment: @Friendly  例えば、「[植物]{しょくぶつ}が[水]{みず}を[必要]{ひつよう}とする」→「水が植物に必要だ」「水が植物に必要となる」とか・・

Comment: @Chocolate: Thank you. Now I understood what your unusual notation means.